# Python Script Loop

Tags: python

I wrote the following python script to implement my version of the game nims/stones

```
def nims_stones(pile, max_stones):

    while pile !=  0:

        move = 0

        while move < 1 or move > max_stones:
            move = int(raw_input("Player 1 How Many Stones"))
        pile -= move

        if pile == 0:
            print "Player 1 wins"

        else:
            print "There are %s stones left." %(pile)



        move = 0

        while move < 1 or move > max_stones:
            move = int(raw_input("Player 2 How Many Stones"))
        pile -= move

        if pile == 0:
            print "Player 2 wins"

        else:
            print "There are %s stones left." %(pile)

    print "Game Over"
```

When I call the function nims_stones(10,5) It seems to work but after player one or player two wins it doesn't exit the loop it doesn't print "Game Over" it just asks for the next move

I don't know why it doesn't exit the loop after a player wins. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I dunno for player 2, but after having printed player 1 wins, you keep changing `pile`. Just `break` when any of the player wins, and make your condition a `while True`. It will be much clearer.

Comment: I tried that it didn't work it simply jumps to Game Over

Answer (score 2):

You should stop the loop when player 1 has emptied the pile. As you have almost the same code for the second player, consider reusing the code. Then you'll also have the empty pile check at the end of the loop:

```
def nims_stones(pile, max_stones):
    player = 2
    while pile !=  0:
        player = 3 - player
        move = 0
        while move < 1 or move > max_stones or move > pile:
            move = int(raw_input("Player %i. How Many Stones" % (player)))
        pile -= move
        print ("There are %s stones left." %(pile))
    print ("Player %i wins" % (player))
    print ("Game Over")
```

NB/ I also added the condition `move > pile` to avoid players taking more than available.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a break statement after each player wins will solve your problem. You should also consider adding logic for when the pile reaches a negative value.

```
while pile !=  0:

    move = 0

    while move < 1 or move > max_stones:
        move = int(raw_input("Player 1 How Many Stones"))
    pile -= move

    if pile == 0:
        print "Player 1 wins"
        break
    else:
        print "There are %s stones left." %(pile)



    move = 0

    while move < 1 or move > max_stones:
        move = int(raw_input("Player 2 How Many Stones"))
    pile -= move

    if pile == 0:
        print "Player 2 wins"
        break
    else:
        print "There are %s stones left." %(pile)

print "Game Over"
```